# Mingw/Msys looking for non-existent file msys-gfortran-5.dll

Tags: windows, dll, fortran, gfortran

I haven't found this file referenced anywhere but, after compiling my .f file, the exe returns this error:

The code execution cannot proceed because msys-gfortran-5.dll was not found. Reinstalling the program may fix this problem.

I had a similar issue asking for a msys-2.0.dll file but I found that one online later.

I played around with different variants such as UCRT64, MINGW64, MINGW32 but to no avail.

Comment: Welcome, please take the [tour] and read [ask] and [mcve]. Do not just down download random dll's from the internet unless you want some viruses. Instead, tell us how you installed gfortran and how exactly you  compiled your code. Show the full commands. The environment on your computer must be properly configures.

Comment: Regarding your last sentence, randomly installing various compiler distribution is one of the ways how corrupt the environment in your system. Uninstall everything, install one of them, say MinGW64, show us the exact commands you did end the exact output you received.

Comment: I followed these guidelines so I ended up getting all of them at once.

https://masuday.github.io/fortran_tutorial/install_gfortran_windows.html

Afterwards I ran gfortran on the .f file.

Comment: How exactly you ran it. What was the complete exact output you got? What does `gfortran -v` say? Where exactly do you run gfortran? In the msys command prompt, in the windows command prompt or in Powershell? You should really at least quickly visit the links I have you. Start with the [tour] and follow to [ask]. We simply do not have enough information to help you.

Comment: Regarding the turorial you used https://masuday.github.io/fortran_tutorial/install_gfortran_windows.html#msys2-and-mingw-w64 it says you should choose one or the other. Either 64-bit or 32-bit. These days, 64-bit should be the right one. Unless you have a specific reason to install both, use only one! As I write before, uninstall everything, install only Msys2 64-bit and run it from the Msys2 window. If you installed some msys-2.0.dll manually from the internet, delete it.

Comment: Also, one does not have to use Msys2, there are other binaries available https://www.mingw-w64.org/downloads/